# Node can't start app due to missing module

Tags: node.js, module, async-await

I have an application that I am running for the first time in a new computer. I keep getting the following error when starting the app

> Error: Cannot find module './src/async'

I checked the application directory and I see the module there. I have tried re-installing the module and doing npm install and still no luck.

Comment: Try `require('async')` instead?

Comment: What I don't understand is why this works fine on another machine.

Comment: Not sure - definitely something to do with the location of the module and the search path. Why not use the standard `node_modules` dir?